# What is wrong with my CASE expression in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have the following query ready, but it doesn't work. It fails with the reason `ERROR: column "yesterday" does not exist Position: 178`.

```
SELECT 'EMAIL' AS comm_mode
    ,EXTRACT(epoch FROM (sent_at - inserted_at)) AS duration
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (EXTRACT(DAY FROM now()) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM inserted_at))=1 THEN "yesterday"
        WHEN (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM now()) - EXTRACT(MONTH FROM inserted_at))=1 THEN "last_month"
    END AS time_period
FROM communications_email
WHERE status = 'sent'
    AND inserted_at >= (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'utc' - INTERVAL '45 day')
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to set the 2 extractions as separate columns, in which case they work and show the values I'm expecting in each individual column. So for column 1 "x_days_ago" it shows the right value, and col2 "x_weeks_ago" it shows the right value, and so on.

(i.e. nothing else seems to be wrong with the rest of the query, only when I add a CASE statement do I get this error.)

I am hoping to get 1 column with "yesterday", "last_week", and "last_month" as string values in a column `time_period` (the rest can have the string "irrelevant" if an "ELSE" is required).

Comment: `"yesterday"` is a column reference. If you want to return a string you need `then 'yesterday'`

Comment: You also have bug in the logic: Your result 1 doesn't mean that it was yesterday when the record was created: The 12th of December minus the 11th of November, but just checking the days, equals 1... Better check like this: CURRENT_DATE - '2022-11-11'::DATE

Comment: Looks like that was my problem. I should pay more attention  Thank you!

@FrankHeikens I didn't consider that. I'll try your route. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: If you want to check if some date (or timestamp) value "yesterday" then something like: `current_date - 1 = inserted_at::date` is better.

Comment: You could even use 'yesterday'::date = inserted_at::date